# C++: Reacting to one empty input vs empty input file

Tags: c++, input

I'm still pretty new at this so this is probably something very simple and I might fail with vocabulary too, but I'll ask anyway because I just can't figure it out myself.

I'm making a program that asks for different commands to change certain coordinates and if you give an empty command it simply asks for a new command. The problem is that if you give the program an input file to read the commands from
(Like this:
./myprogram < inputfile
)
and that file is empty, it ends up in a loop and endlessly asks for a new command. It should be able to exit the program when there's no more input to be read. But how can it make a difference since it can't know if the commands are given from a file or one at a time? Or is there a way for it to know? After all, if they're given manually one at a time, one empty command doesn't mean there won't be more coming. I hope this doesn't sound too silly...

Comment: You just have to check for EOF, e.g. `while (infile) { ... }` the `infile` will evaluate to `false` if it is at EOF

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what a "command" is for you but it sounds as if you are reading individual lines and you want to exclude empty (or misspelled) lines. A simple way to do this is to read lines but first skip leading whitespace until there are no further lines:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(in >> std::ws, line); ) {
    process(line)
}
```

The expression `in >> std::ws` skips all leading whitespace, i.e. all spaces, newlines, tabs, etc. Once this is done, `std::getline()` reads the content of just one line and puts it into `line`. If there isn't any data after leading whitespace was skipped, `std::getline()` fails because the line of the input was reached. If `line` needs to be decoded in some way, you can just put it into a `std::istringstream` and decode it from there.